# "Invalid URI: Invalid port specified" at startup

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uri

I have a project in Visual Studio that used to work fine but I suddenly started receiving the following error:

```
Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.
```

I put a breakpoint at the beginning of my Startup() method which is called first, but that breakpoint doesn't get hit, which tells me that there is some kind of setting or something that Visual Studio must be looking at prior to calling the Startup method that is calling this error.

Does anyone have any idea where I should be looking to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out - I had a semicolon in my launch url. In my launchSettings.json file the applicationUrl was set to "http://localhost:5001;". Removing the semicolon fixed my issue.